# can't start ejabberd,web admin page is not working

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

i am stuck in the installation,and whenever i start ejabberd with ejabberdctl start,it got error like this  ,

> /usr/sbin/ejabberdctl: line 447: /bin/ps: Permission denied,

but the weird part,the port is listened(netstat tulpn), when i registered ejabberd user,it success,and then when i want to start the web admin GUI,it'not sending any data or page isn't working,i am using linux mint 18,and ejabberd 16.01,please help me.

Comment: Any update on this ?:)

Comment: no,i guest not -_-